# how to fix the limitation of this code

Tags: c++

In this code I want to search a word into a string line and if the word is found I want to inverse the word. For example: `This is c++ language` this is the string line and I want to know the word `c++` exists or not. if it exists then print this line `This is ++c language`. So in that line the word has changed from c++ to ++c. How can I do it.

```
# include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int i, j,flage=0,count=0;
    char a[] = { "This is  bangladesh." };
    char b[788];

    cout<<"Before searching\n";
    cout<<"****************************"<<endl;

    for (int m=0; a[m]!='\0';m++) 
    {
        cout<<a[m];
    }

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Write what you want to search from above line: ";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"after searching \n";
    cout<<"*****************************"<<endl;

    for (int p=0; b[p]!='\0';p++) 
    {
        count++;
    }

    for (i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; b[j] != '\0'; j++)
        {
            if (a[j + i] != b[j])
            break;
        }
        if (b[j] == '\0')

            flage = 1;
    }

    if (flage == 1)
    {
        cout << "This is a ";
        for (i =count; i >= 0; i--)
            cout << b[i];
    }

    cout<<"\n\n\n\n";

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `std::string` - which provides a `find` member function, or if you insist on C-style ASCIIZ (i.e. `'\0'` NUL terminated) strings, then using `strstr()` to search, and `strlen()` to find the length?

Comment: but  i want to do it not using library function.

Comment: Then I'd recommend that you implement those functions (`strstr` is the needed one for this purpose) separately, then use it/them to write your higher-level code.  That will give your solution more structure and make it easier to test, while teaching you just as much.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is a learning task, so offering you to use existing functions is out of the question...

Given this, divide your problem into functions:
first, you need to find the starting index of the word you are looking for.
Once you found the starting index, find the last index (which should be really easy)
Now, start swapping: swap the content of the fist index with the last one, move the first one step forward, and the last, one step back and swap again. Do this until you swapped all the word.

One more thing, if I may. give your variables more descriptive names. "a" and "b" are not really descriptive...

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
void reverse(char *x, int begin, int end)
{
        char c;
        if(begin>=end)return;
        c=*(x+begin);
        *(x+begin)=*(x+end);
        *(x+end)= c;
        reverse(x, ++begin, --end);
}

int main()
{

        int i, j,flage=0,count=0;
        char a[] = { "This is bangladesh." };
        char b[788];

        cout<<"Before searching\n";
        cout<<"****************************"<<endl;
        cout<<a;

        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Write what you want to search from above line: ";
        cin>>b;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"after searching \n";
        cout<<"*****************************"<<endl;

        char *ptr=strstr(a,b);
        // in "This is bangladesh" if you search for "is" it will come twice.. so check for word
        while(ptr && *(ptr-1)!=' ') //search for word
        {
          ptr+=strlen(b);
          ptr=strstr(ptr,b);
        }
        if(ptr)
        {
                reverse(b,0,strlen(b)-1);
                cout<<"string found\n";
                memcpy(ptr,b,strlen(b));
                cout<<a;
        }
        else
                cout<<"string not found\n";
        cout<<"\n\n\n\n";
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int i, j,flage=0,count=0;
    char a[] = { "This is  bangladesh." };
    char b[788];

    cout<<"Before searching\n";
    cout<<"****************************"<<endl;

    for (int m=0; a[m]!='\0';m++) 
    {
        cout<<a[m];
    }

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Write what you want to search from above line: ";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"after searching \n";
    cout<<"*****************************"<<endl;

    for (int p=0; b[p]!='\0';p++) 
    {
        count++;
    }

    for (i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; b[j] != '\0'; j++)
        {
            if (a[j + i] != b[j])
            break;
        }
        if (b[j] == '\0')

            flage = 1;
    }

    if (flage == 1)
    {
        cout << "This is a ";
        for (i =count; i >= 0; i--)
            cout << b[i];
    }
   else //Reverse the string
    {
    char *p = b[i], *s = b[i] + strlen(b[i]) - 1;
    while (p < s) {
        char tmp = *p;
        *p++ = *s;
        *s-- = tmp;
     }
   }

    cout<<"\n\n\n\n";

    return 0;

}
```